# Google Analytics not working on 000webhost.com

Tags: google-analytics, web-hosting

I have created a [single HTML](http://jamku.comuf.com/) file in Public HTML folder with below code.

I am not able to view any single visitor on Analytics. I tried following :

1. Shifted Analytics code to Body Tag
2. Waited for 2 days to complete setup. Still no results
3. Removed any '/' as suggested by an answer below.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Jamku Stats</title>

  <script>
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
      i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
      i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
      }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
      a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
      a.async = 1;
      a.src = g;
      m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-30294621-11', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <p>Server is up and running</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why did you \escape\ your quotes ? This will most probably result in a syntax error (which would explain why there is no tracking).

Answer (score 2):

try to remove the escape quotes `\` (waiting two days is correct, since the non-premium Universal Analytics, takes up to 48 hours to compute the data.

Here is your code without the escape quotes:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-1000000-11', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Have updated my code with your suggestion. The real time data is still not showing any data. I will wait for 48 hrs and see.